# Oracle 11g DBCP The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, spring, jdbc

I'm traied to connect oracle with Spring and DBCP.

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCL" />
        <property name="username" value="PMSYSDB" />
        <property name="password" value="********" />
    </bean>
```

but I get: `Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)`

I'm able to connect via SQLDeveloper with this properties:

```
Hostname: localhost
Port    : 1521
SID     : ORCL
username: PMSYSDB
password:
```

so my database is up and running...
 Firewall is off... 
 The database and the tomcat are on the same machine...

Think it's not important, but i use the datasource with Spring Security:

```
     <authentication-manager>
         <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

           users-by-username-query="
              select username, password, enabled 
              from users where username=?" 

           authorities-by-username-query="
              select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
              where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

        />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I used this syntax `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCL` for the connection string. After `/` Oracle expects service name and not SID (ORCL is my SID). 
The solution was to change the connection sring to `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL`

Answer (score 1):

The db might be setup not to allow these kind of connections.
Try this:

```
telnet localhost 1521
```

To see if you can connect on that port.

Comment: Thanks for the respons. After executing "telnet localhost 1521" i get cmd refreshed (C:\Users\myWinUser>), don't know if that is count for connection.
I also checked "lsnrctl status". It returned:
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
, witch tells that the listener listens on port 1521, right?

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your dataSource properties

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the listener after changing and manipulating the

> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora

and

> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

don't forget to refresh listener using the following command in CMD(Run as administrator).

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

After this wait for 1-2 minutes and click on test.